# Multiple internet network interfaces on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, network-manager

First Network Interface(On Ethernet): Public IP: A.A.A.A (Can access internet)

```
enp1s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:39:be:65:33:ec
      inet addr:192.168.0.149  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::8639:beff:fe65:33ec/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2606:6000:6308:c800:8639:beff:fe65:33ec/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:257331 (257.3 KB)  TX bytes:21135 (21.1 KB)`
```

---

Second Network Interface(On USB Modem): Public IP: B.B.B.B (Can access internet)

```
enp0s20u3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:4b:50:b7:ef:da
      inet addr:192.168.1.52  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::344b:50ff:feb7:efda/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:13808 (13.8 KB)  TX bytes:10106 (10.1 KB)
```

---

I am on the ubuntu machine, I want to ssh to a different machine through one of these interfaces, by the information I found on google, I can do on of these

1. `ssh -R 8080:localhost:8080 -i sai.pem ubuntu@107.21.89.216 -b 192.168.1.52`
2. `ssh -R 8080:localhost:8080 -i sai.pem ubuntu@107.21.89.216 -b 192.168.0.149`

The first one works fine, but, the second one just takes forever, with no output.

I also tried curl method by selecting the interfaces, like this

`curl ipinfo.io/ip --interface enp0s20u3`
Outputs B.B.B.B

`curl ipinfo.io/ip --interface enp1s0`
Outputs nothing, just halts, takes forever.

Is there a way I can access ssh by selecting one of the network interfaces, I want to access wget or curl by selecting one of the interfaces too.

## vi /etc/networks/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp

auto enp0s20u3
iface enp0s20u3 inet dhcp

# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface enp1s0 inet6 auto
```

## ip route

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s20u3
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.149
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s20u3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.52
```

Comment: What is the output of `ip route`?

Comment: Added to the question, please check.